# Create less file for custom Theme

Tags: theme, css, less, grunt

How to create new *.less file in Magento 2.3 project ?

**Here is my existing Theme:**

[image]

[image]

**Here is my existing less file that DOES NOT work:**

[image]

**Nothing is work here:**

[image]

[image]

My question is how to add custom less code/file to custom Theme?

any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the less file properly,

Run the Below command and check: (If grunt is installed properly, then your changes will reflect)

```
grunt refresh 
grunt less:YourThemeName
```

Comment: arrgh you are right, voted yours as answer

Comment: This Answer is not valid for our question,  @YusufIbrahim why my answer is not acceptable for this question.

Comment: @Abrar Pathan, My answer is correct as per the default magento. Also your answer is right, but we used that less file on module basis.

Comment: @AbrarPathan actually _extend.less works in both "Magento_Theme\web\css\source" and "app/design/frontend/Senheng/default/web/css/source/", my mistake is I do not run "grunt refresh" before. but yes your anwer provide me more information for debugging

Comment: @YusufIbrahim as per your question is not this issue is not Grunt related. Also, I can see your screenshot your grunt is working fine. In short, my answer is acceptble for this question. I think you are just asking the questions to make points on stack

Comment: come on, before I run "grunt refresh" the less file was not work at all.

Comment: @Abrar Pathan, As per my understanding, Issue was related with grunt, You can check last screenshot, so that i added my answer with grunt refresh command.

Answer (score 1):

I have a review your question and I found that you have done the wrong step to override `_extend.less` file.

The correct way to override _extend.less file:

Go in your theme `Magento_Theme\web\css\source` create `_extend.less` and put your changes in that.

Thanks:)

Comment: hi, thank mate, that's right.. you save my day :)